# Effect for Button after changing backgroundcolor

Tags: android, button, background, click

I changed the background color for my button and now there is no click effect any more.

To get the effect back, my way was to give the button different background colors.

I tried like this:

In drawable-mdpi, I created a `button_bg.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Then, in `strings.xml` I added

```
<style name="darkbutton" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_bg.xml</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

The problem is, that i get the following error when I try to run my application:

```
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.unserekinder/com.example.unserekinder.NeuesKind}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at com.example.unserekinder.NeuesKind.onCreate(NeuesKind.java:22)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    ... 11 more
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    ... 24 more
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi/button_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020000
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1953)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:583)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    ... 27 more
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:178)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1950)
05-06 12:56:43.796: E/AndroidRuntime(20672):    ... 32 more
```

What could be my problem?

Comment: I think you must remove .xml extension from **@drawable/button_bg.xml** in string.xml

Comment: @CRUSADER, Please move transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment but there is still the same mistake!

Comment: added in answer section

Comment: are you still getting same exceptions

Comment: yes, still the sam exceptions!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must remove .xml extension from **@drawable/button_bg.xml** in string.xml

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need to include `android:drawable` attribute into your `<item/>` tag in `button_bg.xml`. Change your `button_bg.xml` to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/pressed"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@color/focused"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/default"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Create a `colors.xml` in your res/values/ folder to save all the color values:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
      <color name="pressed">#ffff0000</color>
      <color name="focused">#ff0000ff</color>
      <color name="default">#ff000000</color>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same mistake!

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project. Still the exact same mistake?

Comment: Did you put your `button_bg.xml` in res/drawable folder only?

Comment: In drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, mdpi and xhddpi.

Comment: You only need one in res/drawable folder.

Comment: but in res there are all these folders. no folder "drawable".

Comment: Then create a folder named "drawable" in res/, the same place where other "drawable-**" are located. Refresh and rebuild.

Comment: Did you remove all the others `button_bg.xml` in drawable-xxx folders?

Comment: Yes, I have! Seems the code might be wrong. Do you have used this sometimes?

Comment: I have used buttons that change colors when pressed. It seems you have multiple errors in different places. Are you sure you still get all the same errors after project clean, refresh your folders on left pane, and rebuild?